# When I using np.savez() function, I got a Error:setting an array element with a sequence. Because I try to save the list like this:[[1,2,3],2.32]

Tags: python, numpy, types, save

When I try to use the function`np.savez()`, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 98, in <module>
    res.save('results.npz')
  File "C:\Users\Downloads\mdts\MDTS\mdts\result.py", line 66, in save
    np.save("a.npy", self.checked_candidates_DS)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in save
  File "D:\basicApps\anaconda\envs\mdts\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 521, in save
    arr = np.asanyarray(arr)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (500, 2) + inhomogeneous part.
```

Because my data looks like [([1, 2, 3], 1.22), ([23,32,2], 2.33)] but much lager.

Can anyone give me a solution? It confused me for a long long time! Thanks for help

like above, I have no idea because there is no arguments in the `np.savez()` function.

Comment: Maybe change to `arr = np.asanyarray(arr, dtype='object')`